# Is it possible to check blame in Sublime Text 2 like in TextMate

Tags: sublime-text-2

I love Textmate's blame very much. Is it possible to have something like that inside of Sublime Text 2?

I mean:

- ability to see each step state (what was added, removed)
- ability to change step
- ability to open some state of file and copy/paste smth

Thanks.

**Update:** I use GIT :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: this answer assumed @InviS is using SVN, but I've since learned he's using GIT.

---

You need to install the SVN package:

- if you haven't done so already, install the Package Control package (it's like apt-get for sublime packages). Instructions are here: http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control/installation
- use sublime's `Command Palette` to run `Install Package`, then search for `SVN` and hit enter to install it (takes a few moments, you'll get an instructions screen when it's done)

Once SVN is installed, you can now use the Command Palette to run various commands, for example type `svci` to run `SVN: Commit...`.

Blame is hidden behind the `SVN: Other...` command, so you need to type something like `svo[enter]bla[enter]` to run it.

You can customise sublime to create additional ways of executing the command, but that'd be a separate question.

Comment: I use GIT (updated my post). And Package Controll is installed. But blame is awful.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't experimented with GIT and Sublime (all my git work is in Xcode). There are several git packages in Package Control... presumably one of them does what you want. You're right, it is pretty basic, sublime is never going to have the kind of version control integration you get from a full IDE like Xcode/Eclipse/etc.

Comment: maybe, it's a pity.. and not convenient.. Will continue my researching of something like that... Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following plugin: https://github.com/kemayo/sublime-text-2-git/wiki

Works great!

Comment: It doesn't work great. It doesn't do points 2 and 3 that InviS asked for. Esp. point 3 I miss, it's enough for me to stay with textmate.